# question regarding statement in bartle's "elements of integration"

Tags: asymptotics, measure-theory

Hi: I just started reading Bartle's "The Elements of Integration", 1966, Wiley, which I really like so far. It concentrates only on the lebesgue integral and leaves general measure theory for other books which I think clarifies a lot of confusion, atleast for me. Anyway, on page 10, he extends the real numbers to include $+\infty$ and -$\infty$. ( and defines positive functions and negative functions but that's not so important for my question ). So, here goes
my confusion.

Assume a fixed measurable space $(X, \textbf{X})$ where $\textbf{X}$ denotes the $\sigma$ algebra on $X$.  ( I don't know why he uses X twice which to me, only makes things more confusing when he's generally EXTREMELY clear. )

Then, quoting Definition 2.7 on the bottom of page 10:

An extended real valued function is $\textbf{X}$ measurable if the
set $\{ x \in X: f(x) \gt \alpha \} \in \textbf{X}$ for each $\alpha$.

The collection of all extended real measurable functions on $\textbf{X}$ on $X$ is denoted as $M(X,\textbf{X})$

(The next two equalities are what I don't understand.)

Observe that if $f \in M(X, \textbf{X})$, then

\begin{equation}
\{x \in X : f(x) = \infty \} = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \{x \in X : f(x) \gt n \}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\{x \in X : f(x) = -\infty \} = \overline {\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{x \in X : f(x) \gt -n \}}
\end{equation}

I don't understand either of the two equalities. Here's some reasoning behind my confusion. The set on the RHS of the first equation is monotone decreasing so it has to be equal to 
$ \{x \in X : f(x) \gt \infty \}$ which clearly has no meaning.

DeMorgan's law can be used to make a similar statement about the second equality. So, I'm not seeing how they can be equalities.  Also, if an explanation is too long or laborious then if someone knows of a book where this is explained, that's fine also. Thanks a lot.

Note that this question is not a knock on the book. I've read ahead some and I can tell already that it's awesome. The explanations are pretty crystal clear in general except for this one Definition.

Comment: Please offer a full reference, and correct the spelling of the author's name in the title

Comment: I interpret this as a more compact way of saying, "if $f(x)>n$ for any integer $n$, we write $f(x) = \infty$", and similar for the second equality. It's $\lim_{N \to \infty} \cap_{n = 1}^{N} \{ x \in X: f(x) > n\}$, which is just the set of functions in $M$ which are not finite at $x$ in the positive direction.

Comment: What justifies your deduction following "so it has to be equal to"?  Indeed, the entire point of these constructions is because that deduction is neither justifiable nor does it make sense, as you note.

Comment: Hi: Ive posted an answer that I obtained from someone not on this list. Thanks.

Comment: @Glen_b: I modified my question to give the full reference but that's the last name of the author as far as I can tell from the book.

Comment: Sorry, then it's the first sentence that you have it wrong in, but in any case it should be capitalized in the title.

Comment: @Glen_b: I'm still not clear on what is wrong or what I should be capitalizing ? If you tell me exactly what you want and that is  in sync with what the book says, I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: make these consistent please: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtdgw.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x \in X$. If $x \in \lbrace x \in X : f(x) = \infty \rbrace$, then $f(x) > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x \in \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n \rbrace$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This gives us that $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n \rbrace$, and we get the inclusion
$$\lbrace x \in X : f(x) = \infty \rbrace \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n \rbrace.$$
Now, if $x \notin \lbrace x \in X : f(x) = \infty \rbrace$, then $x \in \overline{\lbrace x \in X : f(x) = \infty \rbrace} = \lbrace x \in X : f(x) < \infty \rbrace$. Then $f(x) < n_{0}$ for some $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, and so $x \notin \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n_{0} \rbrace$, which means that $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n \rbrace$. By contrapositive, we get the reverse inclusion
$$\lbrace x \in X : f(x) = \infty \rbrace \supset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \lbrace x \in X : f(x) > n \rbrace.$$
So, we get that your first equation holds. Similar logic for the argument to show the second one holds. Admittedly, I'm just now seeing probably why you're confused. The notation $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is usually synonymous with $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, so I don't think the author meant to include $\lbrace x \in X : f(x) > \infty \rbrace$ in the intersection (or else, yeah, you'd just be getting the empty set).